# How do I challenge my HOA's decision on my request to modify my property?

Tags: jurisdiction, court, hoa

I'm in St Louis, Missouri. My house is a part of a HOA. It has bylaws and the bylaws state that alternative dispute resolution may be done through the City of St Louis in accordance with Chapter 435, Mo Rev Stat. In which court do I have to file a petition to have a judge review the board's decision and what form do I need to fill out, as I believe the board's decision is unfair?

Comment: Are you sure the ADL process involves a judge? Mediation and arbitration are usual specified as non-court alternatives - hence the name.

Comment: [Chapter 435](https://revisor.mo.gov/main/OneChapter.aspx?chapter=435) is just the laws surrounding arbitration.

Answer (score 5):

### You can’t go to court

[Chapter 435](https://revisor.mo.gov/main/OneChapter.aspx?chapter=435) is an arbitration statute. By joining the HOA, you agreed that disputes would be resolved through arbitration, not litigation. The contract should specify how the arbitrator is appointed.